# Closed oriented even dimensional manifold with only three non-zero Betti numbers.

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology, projective-space, betti-numbers

The complex and quaternionic projective planes are the examples of a closed oriented even dimensional manifold with exactly three non-zero Betti numbers. For more example see the paper ''Rational analogs of projective planes''. In 
 all these cases the middle Betti number is of even degree. Is there any closed oriented even dimensional manifold has exactly three non-zero Betti numbers with middle Betti number has odd degree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly.  For instance, for any $n$ (even or odd), $S^n\times S^n$ is a closed orientable manifold of dimension $2n$ whose only nonzero Betti numbers are in degree $0,n$ and $2n$.

Comment: These are good examples and fulfill my requirement. have you an example of this kind with middle Betti number one and its degree is odd?  Actually, in case of complex projective plane the middle Betti number is one and even degree.

Comment: That is impossible by Poincare duality.  If the middle Betti number was 1 and odd degree, then if $x$ is an element of the middle degree rational cohomology, $x^2=0$ since the cup product is graded-commutative, which contradicts the fact that the cup product pairing must be perfect by Poincare duality.  More generally, in fact, this shows the middle Betti number must be even if it is in odd degree, since the cup product is a nondegenerate antisymmetric pairing on it.